# fail2ban visual representation of logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, fail2ban

I have already googled this question but couldn't find anything useful.

Does anybody know of a tool that will allow you to see a visual representation/graphic for the fail2ban logs?

Answer (score 0):

There's an add-on for Splunk that will do this, or you could write your own Splunk add-on. https://apps.splunk.com/app/1327/#/documentation

You could also log to MySQL and use any SQL reporting tool you prefer with Fail2SQL. http://fail2sql.sourceforge.net/

The quick and dirty way is to simply tab delimit your fail2ban logs and import everything into Excel for Pivot Table and Pivot Chart reports.